# Update with array filter fails

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
db.getCollection("item").update({},
    {
        "$set":{"questions.optional.$[].items.$[item_field].name":"immediately"}
    },
    {
        "arrayFilters":
        [
            {"item_field.id": "5bf3c907449f4978200dd581"}
        ],
        multi: true
    }
)
```

But the result that I get is this error:

```
"Error parsing array filter :: caused by :: The top-level field name must be an alphanumeric string beginning with a lowercase letter, found 'items_field'"
```

This is the simplified version of the document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("12345678"),
  "questions": {
    "mandatory": [
      {
        "name": "question name",
        "mandatory": true,
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "option1 value"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "optional": [
      {
        "name": "question name",
        "mandatory": false,
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "option4 value"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What does this error mean? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

In your case the problem is in the name "item_field".
MongoDB does not support the underscore character in this scenario.
Changing the name "item_field" to "itemField" resolves the update command:

Update:

```
db.getCollection("item").update({},
    {
        "$set":{"questions.optional.$[].items.$[itemField].name":"immediately"}
    },
    {
        "arrayFilters":
        [
            {"itemField.id": 4}
        ],
        multi: true
    }
)
```

Comment: thank you very much. I couldn't find the relevant documentation anywhere. you saved life